# How can I expose an API from my Corvid site?

Tags: velo

I recently built a Corvid site that shows some inventory listing for a client using a dataset. The client wants to access that data from a third-party app, and for that I need an API that returns the inventory.

How can I expose a REST / HTTP API from a Corvid site?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Corvid's [HTTP functions](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-http-functions.html)

Take a look at the [MyAPI and MyApiClient example](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/wix-tips-and-updates/example-myapi-and-myapiclient) provided by the Corvid team